# Code generation for property 'Type' failed. Error was the value '0' is not a valid for the enum 'detailtype'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, enums

Im working on this VB project on visual studio 2013, and when i make changes to a form and try to save it, keep giving me bellow error doesnt even compile or save.

> Code generation for property 'DisplayType' failed. Error was: 'The value '0' is not valid value for the enum 'EnumDisplayType'.'

Cant figure out the reason for this.

Comment: Share more details....

Comment: it doesn't show other information, just shows me above error

Comment: Are you using any third party assembly in your project? because microsoft has no built in `EnumDisplayType` enum? where it's coming from?

Comment: I've created that enum which im using through out the project. below is the  enum.

 Public Enum EnumDisplayType
        <EnumMember()> KingRoom = 314
<EnumMember()> DoubleRoom = 315
<EnumMember()> SingleRoom = 316
    End Enum

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. 
The problem was with enum as its expecting 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue while simply trying to rename a button in a MS VS 2017 Windows Forms Application. The error I received was:

Code generation for property 'Protocol' failed.  Error was: 'The value '0' is not a valid value for the enum 'ProtocolTypes'.'

As you know, System.Windows.Forms.Button control does not contain a Protocol property. You will need to guess which other object within the application holds that property, and then assign the appropriate value to it.